# Displaying items from database in HTML file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I've recently started learning python flask and ive been having trouble displaying items from a database.

I'm using SQLAlchemy to query the database and passing the results to the home.html template. The code for that looks like:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    get_modules = modules.query.order_by(modules.modulename).all()
    return render_template('home.html', modules = get_modules)
```

Then in the home.html I have this:

```
{% for modulename in modules %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{modulename}}</td>
    <br>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and the output is like this:

- modules('Advanced Web Tech')
- modules('Experiential Design')
- modules('User Centred Organisational Systems')

but I need it to output like this:

- Advanced Web Tech
- Experiential Design
- User Centred Organisational Systems

How would I achieve this?

Comment: `modules.query.order_by(modules.modulename).all()` doesn't return a list of module names, it returns a list of `modules` objects. The output that you are seeing is the `modules.__repr__()`, which is a string representation of the object. If you change `{{modulename}}` to `{{modulename.modulename}}` that should do the trick, then you might just want to consider renaming your loop variable so it reads a bit better.

Comment: @SuperShoot Yeah, that works, thanks for the explanation. I agree with the renaming of the variable. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{% for modulename in modules %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{modulename.modulename}}</td>
    <br>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The return values of `modules.query.order_by(modules.modulename).all()` are basically the rows of the database, so by just printing the `modulename` you are accessing whole row object, that's why you gout `modules(...)` outputed to the screen. To get just a certain column value, just refer to by `modulename.<COLUMN_NAME>`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Seems so obvious after you explained it like that. Thanks